# Getting File not found error when hits the SOLR which is located on Linux box

Tags: c#-4.0

I am using below URL to stream the html file from the content file server to index it in the SOLR, my SOLR is located in Linux box:

> servername:8080/htmlsolr/update/extract?stream.file=//contenfileserverpath/Article/test.html&literal.id=test.html|//contenfileserverpath/Article/test.html&commit=true

Whenever I hit the URL, I am getting the below error:

> HTTP Status 500 - //contenfileserverpath/Article/test.html(No such file or directory) java.io.FileNotFoundException: //contenfileserverpath/Article/test.html(No such file or directory) at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method) at java.io.FileInputStream.(Unknown Source) at org.apache.solr.common.util.ContentStreamBase$FileStream.getStream(ContentStreamBase.java:108) at org.apache.solr.handler.extraction.ExtractingDocumentLoader.load(ExtractingDocumentLoader.java:182) at org.apache.solr.handler.ContentStreamHandlerBase.handleRequestBody(ContentStreamHandlerBase.java:58) at org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:129) at org.apache.solr.core.RequestHandlers$LazyRequestHandlerWrapper.handleRequest(RequestHandlers.java:244) at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.execute(SolrCore.java:1376) at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.execute(SolrDispatchFilter.java:365) at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:260) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127) at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109) at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293) at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859) at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:602) at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489) at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Even though the file is there in the given location, it is throwing the error.